# Fragment with List View and checkbox

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I have a big problem in Fragment that is contain a listview and checkbox,when I check a checkbox and scroll down I notice that there are another checkboxes are checked also , I now that is related to the view and getView() method and i have tried all possible solution related to that but nothing solved the problem ,The method getView cannot be overriding because it's not an Activity it's a Fragment.

please please help me to solve that problem I really tired from this problem ,PLEASE

```
public class Contacts extends Fragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;
ListView list;
CheckBox chbx;
private int count;
boolean checked[];

public Contacts() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts, container, false);

    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    chbx = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


    LoadContactsAyscn lca = new LoadContactsAyscn();
    lca.execute();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

}
```

And this is the LoadContactsAyscn Class that get the phone contacts and put it in a list view

```
class LoadContactsAyscn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Contacts",
                "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String contactName = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phNumber = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contacts.add(contactName + ":" + phNumber);

        }
        c.close();

        return contacts;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> contacts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(contacts);

        pd.cancel();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_text,R.id.Name, contacts);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post what is happening in your onCheckedChanged method. 
I suggest that the error will be located there.

Comment: I didn't add anything to onCheckedChanged method, But when I implement it to the checkbox.setOnChange......... , then the app will stop unfortunately .

Comment: The problems come from the LoadContactsAyscn class
Which effects does it execute method have?